# Blackberry CheckBoxField Tick "Color Change" Can It be Implemented?

Tags: blackberry, checkbox, java-me

The [CheckboxField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/CheckboxField.html) defaults to a blue tick, pictured below. Can the color of the tick be changed to green?

Some work has to be done in the `paint()` method, I think. But, I don't know exactly what.
My code snippet, as well as the default checkbox appearance are below:

[image]

```
CheckboxField checkBoxComments = new CheckboxField("CheckBox",true) {
    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
        // what to do here?
        super.paint(g);
    }
    protected void applyTheme(Graphics arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // do something here? 
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah, let me tell you, I have overridden the applyTheme function and left with no implementation and also I think something should be in the paint method but not sure what.. So searched a lot but couldn't find any solution for it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the code of those attempts, and include a screenshot showing how those attempts are falling short.

Comment: I don't know what you expect overriding applyTheme will do since it is not a method implemented or inherited by CheckBoxField. The tick is likely a image that is drawn over the box by the paint method.

Comment: I brought over the code snippet from your duplicate question, which had a little more detail.  Unfortunately, there's little demonstrated in the code snippet - the paint method is overridden, but the implementation doesn't actually change the behavior in any way.

Comment: @Richard How can we override our image(which will be green tick) in the checkbox?

Comment: @MichaelDonohue  Thanks Michael for the editing, Yeah it do not change the behavior but I don't know what to write to change the color(as for now info its an image) So how can we draw our image instead of that tick image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish I knew of an *easier* way, but one way that certainly will work is to simply make your `CheckBoxField` a custom field, that actually is a *button* field.  This custom field will have a different image for the checked, and unchecked state.

As a basis for this custom field, I started with the [BitmapButtonField](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BitmapButtonField.java) from the BlackBerry Advanced UI open source project, as a template.  This is a good example of creating fields with custom behaviour.  In the project's `BitmapButtonField`, they maintain two images, one for the button's **normal** state, and one for the **focus** state.  In our case, we can maintain images for the **checked**, and **unchecked** states.  You could certainly also add more states, by having checked-unfocused, checked-focused, unchecked-unfocused, and unchecked-focused.  But, I'll leave that to you.  This example should show you how to do that.

First, [add the BaseButtonField class](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Advanced%20UI/src/com/samples/toolkit/ui/component/BaseButtonField.java) to your project.  Then, extend that with this class:

```
public class ImageCheckboxField extends BaseButtonField {

   private boolean _checked = false;
   private Bitmap[] _bitmaps;
   private static final int UNCHECKED = 0;
   private static final int CHECKED = 1;
   //private static final int FOCUS_UNCHECKED = 2;
   //private static final int FOCUS_CHECKED = 3;

   public ImageCheckboxField( boolean checked )
   {
      this( checked, 0 );
   }

   public ImageCheckboxField( boolean checked, long style ) 
   {
      // TODO: if you're going to use multiple instances, you 
      //  may want to optimize to avoid loading these PNGs each time
      this( checked, Bitmap.getBitmapResource("box-unchecked.png"), Bitmap.getBitmapResource("box-checked.png"), style);
   }

   protected ImageCheckboxField( boolean checked,  Bitmap uncheckedState, Bitmap checkedState )
   {        
      this( checked, uncheckedState, checkedState, 0 );
   }

   protected ImageCheckboxField( boolean checked, Bitmap uncheckedState, Bitmap checkedState, long style ) {
      super( Field.FOCUSABLE | style );

      if( (uncheckedState.getWidth() != checkedState.getWidth())
            || (uncheckedState.getHeight() != checkedState.getHeight()) ){

         throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Image sizes don't match" );
      }

      _bitmaps = new Bitmap[] { uncheckedState, checkedState };
   }

   public void clickButton() {
      // override this to toggle state on click
      setChecked(!getChecked());
      super.clickButton();
   }

   public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
      _checked = checked;
      invalidate();
   }

   public boolean getChecked() {
      return _checked;
   }        

   private void setImage( Bitmap uncheckedState ){
      _bitmaps[UNCHECKED] = uncheckedState;
      invalidate();
   }

   private void setCheckedImage( Bitmap checkedState ){
      _bitmaps[CHECKED] = checkedState;
      invalidate();
   }

   public int getPreferredWidth() {
      return _bitmaps[UNCHECKED].getWidth();
   }

   public int getPreferredHeight() {
      return _bitmaps[UNCHECKED].getHeight();
   }

   protected void layout( int width, int height ) {
      setExtent( _bitmaps[UNCHECKED].getWidth(), _bitmaps[UNCHECKED].getHeight() );
   }

   protected void paint( Graphics g ) {
      // TODO: uncomment this if you draw different images based on focus
      //boolean focused = g.isDrawingStyleSet( Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS );
      int index = UNCHECKED;
      //if (focused) {
      //   index = getChecked() ? FOCUS_CHECKED : FOCUS_UNCHECKED;
      //} else {
      index = getChecked() ? CHECKED : UNCHECKED;
      //}      
      g.drawBitmap( 0, 0, _bitmaps[index].getWidth(), _bitmaps[index].getHeight(), _bitmaps[index], 0, 0 );
   }

   /**
    * With this commented out the default focus will show through
    * If an app doesn't want focus colours then it should override this and do nothing
    **/
   /*
       protected void paintBackground( Graphics g ) {
           // Nothing to do here
       }
    */

   protected void drawFocus( Graphics g, boolean on ) {
      // Paint() handles it all
      g.setDrawingStyle( Graphics.DRAWSTYLE_FOCUS, true );
      paintBackground( g );
      paint( g );
   }
}
```

I've tried to imitate some of the native `CheckboxField` API, so this new `ImageCheckboxField` class can be dropped in where you would normally use the standard `CheckboxField`.  I did not mimic the label functionality, because I often find that I can't use the built-in labels, and wind up placing my own separate `LabelField` anyway.

See below for the two images I used for this.  You can resize them if need be (they actually came from an iPhone Retina app that I built).  If the green I picked isn't quite what you want, [here is the Photoshop tutorial I used to get the image green](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/gradient-map/), from a basic black and white image, also shown:

[image]
[image]

[image]

### Limitations

I didn't address focus drawing here.  I don't know what you want on that.  Currently, there is no focus drawing at all.  You can either handle that by creating two new PNG images to draw.  Or, you could comment out the `drawFocus()` method in `BaseButtonField`, which will show the default BlackBerry blue focus gradient around the transparent checkbox edges.  Or, you could make the white background of the images transparent, to show through even more of the blue gradient.  Or, you could implement the drawing yourself, with `Graphics#drawShadedFilledPath()` in either `paint()` or `drawFocus()`.  It's up to you.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you have trouble getting the appearance the way you'd like, when the field is *focused*, try one of the techniques I mention at the bottom of the answer.  If it doesn't work, just post a new question, asking just about focus drawing, showing the class above (especially if you make any modifications to it), and we should be able to get you something good.  It's unfortunate that this kind of thing isn't easier with BlackBerry Java :(

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Totally agree, Very unfortunate. Thanks !